# jcenter.bintray.com give 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: android, kotlin, jcenter

I'm getting 502 from Bintray when I try to import new dependencies

e tried: Clear cache/restart Updating my gradle version Updating Exoplayer version

Still getting the error from Bintray. Best regards.

Comment: Try again tomorrow, and hope that Google gets ExoPlayer's transitive dependencies off of JCenter sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago JCenter has an outage, history [here](https://status.gradle.com/). 
[Sporadic 502 Bad Gateway, 500 Internal Server Error for maven-metadata.xml resources](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/nv93msj8q658)